# How to select data in scrapy from html file having both class and id?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```html
<div class="section-body" id="section-2"><p>Most people with aortic stenosis do not develop symptoms until the disease is advanced. The diagnosis may have been made when the health care provider heard a heart murmur and performed tests.</p><p>Symptoms of aortic stenosis include:</p><ul><li>Chest discomfort: The chest pain may get worse with activity and reach into the arm, neck, or jaw. The chest may also feel tight or squeezed.</li><li>Cough, possibly bloody.</li><li>Breathing problems when exercising.</li><li>Becoming easily tired.</li><li>Feeling the heartbeat (palpitations).</li><li>Fainting, weakness, or dizziness with activity.</li></ul><p>In infants and children, symptoms include:</p><ul><li>Becoming easily tired with exertion (in mild cases)</li><li>Failure to gain weight</li><li>Poor feeding</li><li>Serious breathing problems that develop within days or weeks of birth (in severe cases)</li></ul><p>Children with mild or moderate aortic stenosis may get worse as they get older. They are also at risk for a heart infection called bacterial endocarditis.</p></div></div></section>
```

I have above script and I want to scrap the data in the list. i.e. in 
 
I have tried following commands in scrapy but not working. It is giving '[]' as a output.

```
 response.css("article div.section-body p").extract() <-- this is giving all info under section body but I want only under section-2
  response.css("article div.section-body.section-2 p::text").extract()
 response.xpath("//article/*[contains(@id, 'setion-2')]").extract()
```

please help me to extract. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
response.css("article div.section-body#section-2 p::text").extract()
```

`div.section-body#section-2` means select DIV having both Class `section-body` and ID `section-2`

Note that ID is selected by `#` and class is selected by `.` ... So your CSS Selector posted in your question was wrong.

Comment: import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medical"

    start_urls = ['https: // medlineplus.gov / ency / article / 000178.htm']


    def parse(self, response):
        yeild
        {
            'topic': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
            'symptoms': response.css("article div#section-2 li::text").extract()
        }                                                                                 When I'm running this with     -->  scrapy crawl medical -o medical.json
it is not giving any output in json file.

Comment: does that show scraped data in scrapy logs in CLI/Terminal?

Comment: No, it is not showing data to be crawled it is showing some error in terminal   ------>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "F:\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\quotes_spider.py", line 11, in parse
    yeild
NameError: global name 'yeild' is not defined
I tried with indentation correction but not working

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5X87PK                         Its just a code to extract from one page.